# Safari extension for adding arbitrary Javascript to a page?

Tags: safari, web-browsing, safari-extensions, javascript, css

Is there a way to do this?

I know I can use Stylish for adding arbitrary CSS to pages on a per-domain basis. Looking for something similar to add Javascript.

For example, let's say I wanted to turn the text red for any h1 element on a particular site if the content of that h1 element is "News". Can't do that with CSS, need to do it with Javascript. Is there any extension I can use to add this? Or would I have to write my own?

Comment: Is this basically what "stylish" did as an extension that many people are looking for replacements? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338406/stylish-replacement-for-mac

Answer (score 1):

The [*dotjs* Safari extension](https://github.com/wfarr/dotjs.safariextension) sounds like it will do what you want. It injects the JavaScript (from your `~/.js` directory) that is served up by a small, local Ruby web server from the original [*dotjs* Chrome extension](https://github.com/defunkt/dotjs).

Answer (score 1):

I previously used [dotjs](https://github.com/wfarr/dotjs.safariextension) and [dotcss](https://github.com/maman/dotcss.safariextension) for Safari. As I relied on these a lot, I've written an extension for Safari 12 that provides the same functionality in one extension with a simpler setup.

In case you're interested, I have an [introductory blog post](https://phili.pe/posts/introducing-page-extender-for-safari/). The extension is [available on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pageextender-for-safari/id1457557274?ls=1&mt=12) ($5). It's [open source](https://github.com/fphilipe/PageExtender.app), so you're also welcome to compile it yourself for free.