# Stylish Replacement for Mac

Tags: safari, software-recommendation, safari-extensions

I wonder if anyone is aware of any replacement for [Stylish](http://sobolev.us/stylish/).

Answer (score 4):

There is a paid ($3 in US) application [Cascadea](https://cascadea.app). I’m happy with it, because it is [Safari App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions) instead of the Legacy Safari Extensions (`.safariextz` files). It seems to only work with User CSS (`*.user.css`) though, so you may want to write to support team (support@cascadea.app) to confirm before you pay.

Answer (score 3):

I previously used [dotjs](https://github.com/wfarr/dotjs.safariextension) and [dotcss](https://github.com/maman/dotcss.safariextension) for Safari. As I relied on these a lot, I've written an extension for Safari 12 that provides the same functionality in one extension with a simpler setup.

Not sure if this is enough for your needs as it only offers injection of CSS and JS files based on the page's domain name.

In case you want to find out more, I've written an [introductory blog post](https://phili.pe/posts/introducing-page-extender-for-safari/). The extension is [available on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pageextender-for-safari/id1457557274?ls=1&mt=12) ($5). It's [open source](https://github.com/fphilipe/PageExtender.app), so you're also welcome to compile it yourself for free.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced Stylish with [**FreeStyler**](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=ws.freestyler.freestyler-SRV36C8E2C) which provides the same functionality just with a slightly worse UI. There’s no automatic import path from files or another extension, so moving styles were a case of manual copy-paste and configuring the applicable hosts/URL prefixes.

Comment: As the original Stylish (including the Safari version?) had massive security implications and apparently turned really rogue: did you control for that in FreeStyler?

Comment: FreeStyler has been removed in Safari version 12 and later

Comment: @LаngLаngС I'm a developer of `Stylish for Safari` and i can confirm that there is no any security issues with my version. Original Chrome/Firefox version was involved in this incident, not mine. Mine are open source and verified by Apple multiple times. GA - optional and can be turned off in settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net). It's not totally Stylish but it can do the same.

Comment: It's really not as nice as Stylish.